# How do I set NODE_ENV=production on Electron app when packaged with electron-packager?

Tags: environment-variables, electron

How do I make packaged releases of my Electron application set `NODE_ENV=production` when packaged with `electron-packager`?

Comment: Have you considered going the other way around, as in setting `NODE_ENV=dev` or something similar for the environments you _can_ pass env variables to? In my case that did the trick as in development I'm using Webpack's dev server - which is always started with `NODE_ENV=dev` unlike the standalone app. EDIT: sorry, just saw how old the question is, but I'll leave the comment here in case the same thing works for someone else that ends up here.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

UPDATE 2019/12

Use `app.isPackaged`: https://electronjs.org/docs/api/app#appispackaged-readonly

It returns true if the app is packaged, false otherwise. Assuming you only need a check if it's in production or not, that should do it. The env file solution detailed below would be more suitable if you had different environments/builds with different behaviors.

---

To my knowledge, you can't pass env vars to a packaged electron app on start (unless you want your users to always start it from the command line and pass it themselves). You can always set that env variable in your application like this: `process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production'`. You could integrate that with electron-packager by having an env file that gets set in your build and is required by your application to determine what environment it's in.

For example, have a packaging script that looks like:

```
"package": "cp env-prod.json src/env.json && npm run build"
```

and in your `src/main.js` file:

```
const appEnv = require('./env.json');
console.log(appEnv) //=> { env: "prod", stuff: "hey" }
//you don't really need this, but just in case you're really tied to that NODE_ENV var
if(appEnv.env === 'prod') {
  process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production';
}
```

Comment: That is a quality workaround, certainly better than what I did. There's a package I'm relying on that relies on less checks (i.e. runs faster) when NODE_ENV is set to production (clearly their devs are reliant on webpack).

Answer (score 0):

You can set it in 2 ways.

By command line with `--no-prune` see here in the usage [guide](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-packager/blob/master/usage.txt)

Or programmatically with this API

```
var packager = require('electron-packager');
var options = {
  'arch': 'ia32',
  'platform': 'win32',
  'dir': './'
  'prune': true //this set the enviroment on production and ignore dev modules
};
packager(options, function done_callback (err, appPaths) { /* … */ })
```

For more options see this [guide](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-packager/blob/master/docs/api.md#electron-packager-api)

Comment: I'm using `prune` now, that only prevents devDeps from being installed. This doesn't set the environment variable on the running app.

Comment: acording to npm documentation prune set the enviroment on production
https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/prune, you can also do it with the command line